# Commutator subgroup $G'$ of a solvable group $G$ is not $G$

Tags: group-theory

Here is the question:

> Let $G$ be a solvable group. Prove that $G \neq G'$.

Is this correct?
Suppose $G=G'$, then the only abelian quotient of $G$ must be $\{1\}=G/G'$. So there is no proper normal subgroup $H$ of $G$ that gives abelian quotient $G/H$. So then in the normal serie, it should end with $G \triangleright G \triangleright \{1\}$. but $G/\{1\}$ doesn't give abelian composition factor. I'm just unsure if each $G_i$ is the definition of composition series must be proper normal subgroup of $G_{i-1}$?

Here is definition of solvable group(before lemma 25.1.1):[image]

Comment: Not every solvable group has a composition series. For example $({\mathbb Z},+)$ has no such series. So you should prove it without using composition series.

Comment: Ok I guess I meant normal series. That is how my note defined solvable groups

Comment: It is not correct for the trivial group $G=1$, where we have $G=G'$. Otherwise it follows from the derived series.

Comment: OK, so $G$ has a normal series $G =G_0 > G_1 > \cdots G_k = 1$, where $G/G_1$ is abelian, so $G' \le  G_1$ and we are done. Of course, as Dietrich Burde points out, this only works if $|G|>1$.

Comment: It'd perhaps be helpful, for the question, to write down what **your** definition of "solvable group" is. Sometimes it requires something on the derived series, some other times it says something about a subnormal series with abelian factors...

Comment: @DonAntonio And at other times in involves something about a normal series with abelian factors, which  apparently is the one intended here.

Comment: The definition that you have quoted there is garbled. "Composition factors" refers to the quotients in a composition series, so "normal series in which all the composition factors are abelian groups" does not make sense.

Comment: BTW, a *lemma* usually defines nothing. In this case, it merely characterizes finite solvable groups. The definition must surely is before that.

Comment: Yes, it is right before the lemma in the note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are requiring that $G$ is not trivial.
We have two cases:

1) If $G$ is an abelian group. Then $G'=0$, but $G=G'$ is not trivial. Contradiction.

2) If $G$ is not abelian, and $G'=G$ fails the fact that $G$ is solvable.